# Xcode: he first view doesn't see changes made by the second one

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, view, storyboard

I'm a very newbie in the obj-c programming and have some troubles trying to change values between two views. I'm using Xcode 4.5 and storyboards and I've some problems with passing a changed value from the second view to the first one.

Here's my 2 very simple views (posting the link as I'm a new user and can't post images):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4o2bblu1p57zod/img.png

These views are assigned to the same class (ViewController) and the code I'm using to change the 2 labels is:

```
-(IBAction)setLabel:(id)sender
{
    if (myTextField.text.length != 0) {
        myLabel1.text = myTextField.text;
        myLabel2.text = myTextField.text;
    }
}
```

The problem is that Label1 changes correctly its text, but there's nothing to do with Label2! It doesn't want to change...

I think I'm trying to do something that can be made in others ways...Can you please tell me if it's correct?

Comment: create a custom delegate - they are surprisingly easy to do and create a recursive relationship among objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Protocol-Delegate approach to update content in First view.

I suggest you to visit this [sample link](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/15/passing-data-between-views-tutorial-using-a-protocol-delegate-in-your-iphone-app/).

Answer (score 0):

Your two view controllers may be of the same class but they are going to be different objects at runtime.  You have a segue between them and when that executes a new instance will be created.  Since the 'label2' of the second instance is not displayed on its screen, your assignment doesn't produce a visible change.